# Adding contents in an RDD[(Array[String], Long)] into a new array into a new RDD: RDD[Array[(Array[String], Long)]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an `RDD[Array[String]]` which I zipWithIndex:

```
val dataWithIndex = data.zipWithIndex()
```

Now I have a `RDD[(Array[String], Long)]`, I would like to add all the pairs in the RDD to an array and still have it in the RDD. Is there an efficient way to do so? My final datastructure should be `RDD[Array[(Array[String], Long)]]` where the RDD essentially only contains one element.

Right now I do the following, but it is very ineffective because of `collect()`:

```
val dataWithIndex = data.zipWithIndex()
val dataNoRDD = dataWithIndex.collect()
val dataArr = ListBuffer[Array[(Array[String], Long)]]()
dataArr += dataNoRDD
val initData = sc.parallelize(dataArr)
```

Comment: just do `dataWithIndex.map(Array(_))` . you should get what you want

Comment: Simple enough, thank you!

Comment: my pleasure @osk

Comment: Hi again, sorry to bother. I'm having some issues with this. The RDD that gets created is my desired datastructure, however the RDD contains more than one element.

Comment: With a simpler example, lets say I have an RDD[Int] = (1,2,3). I would like to get an RDD[Array[Int]] which is on the form [(1,2,3)], i.e RDD.count() should yield 1. And to access for example the number 3, after RDD.collect(), you would write RDD.collect()(0)(2).

Comment: you collect your `RDD[Int]` and then make it `RDD[Array[Int]]` for example `val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3)).collect()
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(rdd1))`

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, although the collect() is kind of expensive and I'm unsure whether I can collect all data on the driver in the long run. Thanks though. No way without collecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion is that this seems to be extremely hard to do with standard functionality.

Instead, if the input comes from a Hadoop filesystem it is possible to do. This can be done by extending certain Hadoop classes.

First you need to implement `WritableComparable<>` and define a custom format that the RDD will contain. In order for this to work, you need to define a custom `FileInputFormat` and extend it in order to support your custom `Writable`. In order for `FileInputFormat` to know what to do with data being read, a custom `RecordReader` has to be written by extending it and here specifically the method `nextKeyValue()` has to be written which defines what each RDD element will contain. All of these three are written in Java, but with some simple tricks it is possible to do.